# Design : How to drive a dynamic set of similar classes from a program

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have to make a design decision in my application. The following is the scenario.

I have a set of service classes that are spread across different maven modules in my application.

```
public class ServiceA 
{
   public void startA()
   {
       ....
   }
}

public class ServiceB
{
   public void startB()
   {
       ....
   }
}
```

I have got 8 such service classes currently.More may be added in future.

All of these service classes' start has to be called in a driver program.
The number of services may vary with time.And when it does,I want to avoid updating Driver program.

I have thought about making the services to implement an interface.But at runtime, the list of services needs to be available for the driver to start them.

Driver is the first to be executed when the application is launched and is expected to start the services.

Please suggest as to how to go about this.

Comment: "I have thought about making the services to implement an interface.But at runtime, the list of services needs to be available for the driver to start them.
" - can you clarify how an interface is failing to do what you want?

Comment: Interface will only ensure I get to start the services polymorphically. I also need a solution to fetch the list of all the services that would have implemented this interface.

Answer (score 1):

You could turn it around and make all services register themselves to the driver.

They can all be spring beans with the driver injected.

If you don't want the services to know about the driver, you can introduce either a middle man for them that has a dependency on both the service and the driver, or you can to it trough a @Configuration class.

Update:

You can use the ServiceLoader class to locate your services have a look at this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html).

And here is a library that makes it somewhat easier to use: [ServicePluginLoader](https://github.com/kristofa/service-plugin-loader)

Comment: Services cannot register themselves to the driver as the driver is the first to be executed when the application is launched and is expected to start the services immediately.

Comment: Can you please update the question to indicate this?

Answer (score 0):

Have them all implement a common interface that includes a `start()` method.

Load them with `Class.forName()` after obtaining the fully qualified class names and create new instances via reflection (`Class.newInstance()`) which will require that they all have no-arg constructor.

Spring already does the class and instance management part, so you should probably investigate it, leaving you with only the common interface to worry about.

Comment: Ok. Say I register all the classes to a Spring application context. Using this context ,will I be able to get the objects of only the classes who have implemented the common interface?

Comment: Your pointer to spring  class and instance management part helped.Posting my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a configuration class to detect and register only the classes that implement the IsService interface.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.subex.roc"} , 
              useDefaultFilters = false , 
              includeFilters = {@Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,value = IsService.class)})
public class ServiceRegisterConfig 
{
}
```

Fetching the registered classes and calling start() polymorphically.

```
public void initServerServices()
{
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    context.register(ServiceRegisterConfig.class);
    context.refresh();

    for (String beanDfn : context.getBeanDefinitionNames()) 
    {
      if (context.getBean(beanDfn) instanceof IsService) {
      IsService service = (IsService) context.getBean(beanDfn);
      service.start();
    }
 } 
}
```